# PHP, .htaccess apache unified mod_rewrite just with one variable

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm quite new to .htaccess and mod_rewrite. I can prepare seo friendly URLs with specific urls. However I would like to make one which will unify everything for me.

**For example;**

```
Original : http://www.domain.com/index.php?module=profile&id=1.
SEO : http://www.domain.com/profile/1
.htaccess Code: RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)  ?module=profile&id=$1 [L]
```

As you can see I have to specify `profile` and any other module name in `.htaccess` file

What I would like to do is;

```
Original : http://www.domain.com/?request=module/profile/id/1/other/any
SEO : http://www.domain.com/module/profile/id/1/other/any
```

However the same logic of mod_rewrite doesn't apply.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)  ?request=$1 [L]
```

Is there anyway around this problem?

My full .htaccess;

```
# Disable server signature
ServerSignature Off
####################################################################
# MOD REWRITE
####################################################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.*)  /index.php?request=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I can use it this way without any problem;

```
# Disable server signature
ServerSignature Off
####################################################################
# MOD REWRITE
####################################################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^content/(.*) ?module=content&request=$1
</IfModule>
```

**WORKING VERSION**

```
# Disable server signature
ServerSignature Off
####################################################################
# MOD REWRITE
####################################################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?request=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

However I still need to specify atleast one thing.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your approach, you just need a tiny fix:

**EDIT 2**

```
RewriteRule (.*)  index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

That's it. Btw. you might as well just redirect everything to `index.php` and look for request parameters within the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal.

**EDIT**

The problem lies here:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>        <<<<<
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Don't compress
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary
#Dealing with proxy servers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>        <<<<<
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
</IfModule>                     <<<<<
```

**EDIT 3**

```
...
RewriteEngine on

# Pass any request not referring directly to a file or directory in the
# filesystem to index.php    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply **aefxx**. However I get 500 Internal Server error with this one. I added my full .htaccess file. Maybe I do sth wrong before this rule. I will be glad if you could point me to the right direction. I prefer to not get into superglobals but thank you for the info.

Comment: Chances are that the last `</IfModule>` is misplaced, try to paste it just right before the `# GZIP` comment.

Comment: Something else I've noticed: the rule `RewriteRule /  index.php [L]` is superfluous as this is handled by **mod_dir** (very likely to be available to you out of the box). The relevant directive should read `DirectoryIndex index.php [...]`, where "..." could be anything you like as a fallback.

Comment: I have updated my current .htaccess file. I get `Object not found!` error this time. Mod re-write is seriously pain in the neck :(

Comment: I have removed everything but server signature and mod-rewrite rules. I still get `Object not found!` error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You need to remove the `/` off the line that reads `Rewrite Rule (.*) /index.php?request=$1 [L]`.

Comment: I have also tried without it just to see how it would behave. There are 2 problems though. 1. No CSS or JS files are read therefore page looks really ugly. 2. When I dump `var_dump($_GET['request'])` I get `index.php` output. Now I'm really confused.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's right. You need to exclude files/resources that you don't want to get rewritten. I'll update ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as expected now. I really appreciate your help.